# How to use JavaScript to supply a client certificate to a SIgnalR hub

Tags: javascript, signalr, client-certificates

I have managed (with the help of numerous sites and stackoverflow questions) to create a self-hosted SignalR hub that will process and authenticate SSL client certificates.  I can access that hub from .Net code via using HubConnection.AddClientCertificate().  I see the certificate in the server etc.

However, I need to call this same server/hub from Jscript with a client certificate and I have found nothing to indicate that this action can be done.

Comment: Anyone? I have the same problem. Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: Any thoughts about this? Sill experiencing the same issue